# Rewrite power series

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

I have a series

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{n} a^{2n-k} f(k) g(n-k),$$
where $f,g$ are two functions.
Now, I want to rewrite this as a series in terms of powers of $a,$ i.e.

$$\sum_{u=0}^{\infty} a^{u} \cdot{ \text{something}}.$$

Does anybody know whether such an index shift or change of variables is possible ?

Comment: Note that $2n - k = k + 2\cdot (n-k)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer note that $k+2(n-k)=2n-k$ ;-). Could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: Typo, sorry, fixed now. Basically, your series is $F(a)\cdot G(a^2)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer what exactly is $F,G$ and $a$ in your notation? I mean I understand that the power is the sum of $k+2(n-k)$ but how does this help me finding my representation in terms of powers of $a$?

Comment: By the way: The term $a^{2n-k}f(n-k) g(k)$ is due to multiplying out a power $(a\alpha+a^2 \beta)^n$

Comment: You have $\sum\limits_{v,w} a^vf(v)a^{2w}g(2w)$. Now when you group by powers of $a$, how does the coefficient look?